# VBA Check if Value is in the list with condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

```
Sub PullUniques()
LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & LastRowColumnA)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B" & LastRowColumnA), rngCell) <> 0 And _
       Range(WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B" & LastRowColumnA), rngCell) <> 0).Offset(0, 1).Row <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please correct Item" & rngCell & " Amount Data"
    End If
Next
```

This code is looking up Column B to see if column A has any same values.
The code works fine if I do not use second line of if statement, but when I tried to add second condition column A is matching B and column C's value is not greater than 0, it does not work. How can I make this code work?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B" & LastRowColumnA), rngCell) <> 0` does not return a viable address that the RAnge() can use.  It returns a TRUE/FALSE not a cell reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to check, 

1) if the value in A exist in column B and 

2) if TRUE, is the value in column C less than or equal to 0. 

If that's what you need, the code below should work.

```
Sub PullUniques()
LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & LastRowColumnA)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B" & LastRowColumnA), rngCell) <> 0 And _
       Range("C" & rngCell.Row).Value <= 0 Then
       MsgBox "Please correct Item" & rngCell & " Amount Data"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

However, if your condition is,
1) if the value in A the same as value in B and

2) if TRUE, is the value in column C less than or equal to 0. 

then you don't need to use `countif`

```
Sub PullUniques()
LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & LastRowColumnA)
Debug.Print Range("B" & rngCell.Row).Value & "/" & Range("C" & rngCell.Row).Value
    If Range("B" & rngCell.Row).Value = rngCell And _
       Range("C" & rngCell.Row).Value <= 0 Then
       MsgBox "Please correct Item" & rngCell & " Amount Data"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I wanted!